# pagination and load data on scroll down

Tags: javascript, ajax

I was trying ajax and javascript. I was able to populate a table with the data, apparently I only loaded 5 pagination of data. The problem is what If the list gets to 1000, I need to load data while mouse scrolling down and while doing pagination.

I already tried in fiddle

here is the link:
https://jsfiddle.net/y7gadqkk/108/

```
jQuery.ajax({
        url: "https://api.fda.gov/drug/label.json?limit=5",
        success: function (data) {
        //append to table
        }
});
```

I'm using the openfda api btw. The problem I don't know how to achieve pagination or data loading while mouse scrolling down.

Your help is much appreciated.
Thank you.

Comment: I think you should try jQuery plugin for that, for ex. [jscroll](http://jscroll.com/)

Comment: @MehdiDehghani how can you apply it to ajax? or what ive done

Comment: See the example and read the docs, also there is other plugins too, just google for that

Answer (score 0):

you can use jquery's [**scroll event**](https://api.jquery.com/scroll/), so when you scroll your mouse, the event will be triggered. In event handler, you can check the last record's position, and loading new data when you think necessary.